# Foreach with multidimensional arrays in Java

Tags: java

I read Java: The Complete Reference(9th). In Character 5: Control Statements - Iterating Over Multidimensional Arrays section
Write:

> The enhanced version of the for also works on multidimensional arrays.
>   Remember, however, that in Java, multidimensional arrays consist of
>   arrays of arrays. (For example, a two-dimensional array is an array of
>   one-dimensional arrays.) This is important when iterating over a
>   multidimensional array, because each iteration obtains the next array,
>   not an individual element. Furthermore, the iteration variable in the
>   for loop must be compatible with the type of array being obtained. For
>   example, in the case of a two-dimensional array, the iteration
>   variable must be a reference to a one-dimensional array. **In general,
>   when using the for-each for to iterate over an array of N dimensions,
>   the objects obtained will be arrays of N–1 dimensions.** To understand
>   the implications of this, consider the following program. It uses
>   nested for loops to obtain the elements of a two-dimensional array in
>   row- order, from first to last.

I can't understand why "to iterate over an array of N dimensions,
the objects obtained will be arrays of N–1 dimensions". Is it true?

Comment: Did you look at the "following program"?  It seems that the example might have a good explanation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An array of *N* dimensions is really an array of (*N*-1)-dimensional arrays. Therefore, when we iterate over an array of *N* dimensions, we are iterating over all of its constituent (*N*-1)-dimensional arrays, as indicated.

For example, consider a 2-dimensional array:

```
int[][] array = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};
```

This is really an array of 1-dimensional arrays: `{1,2,3}` and `{4,5,6}`.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes My OCD gets the best of me sometimes.

Comment: :) I'm always having to adjust this too, too much updating. On [tag:java] it is worse as it is more of a competition.

Answer (score 4):

Consider a tridimensional matrix (mathematically defined).

When you iterate through the rows, you are getting two dimensional matrices, and when you iterate through each of the two dimensional matrices you are getting one dimensional vectors.

```
    // Three dimensions
    String[][][] stringArray = new String[3][3][3];

    // Iterating over one dimension
    // results in two dimensional array
    for (String[][] strings : stringArray) {
        // Iterating over one dimension
        // results in one dimensional array
        for (String[] strings2 : strings) {
            // Iterating over one dimension
            for (String string : strings2) {

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Imagine your multi-dimensional array as (x, y, z). When you iterate over first coordinate, you fix x (x = 1, 2, ..., n) and get (y, z) 2d-array.

Then you fix y(y = 1, 2, ..., m) and get (z) 1d-array.

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate over an array you "set" one dimension and leave the others not set. So when you have a N dimension array, when you enter the loop you use a N-1 dimension array (inside the for-each loop).